# MySQL How to get first row from subquery when using aggregate function

Tags: mysql, subquery, aggregate, mysql-8.0

**This is my Query:**

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(runs_scored) - SUM(IF(extra_type_id = 4, 1, 0)) AS Balls,
    SUM(runs_scored) + SUM(IF(extra_type_id IN (2 , 4),
        extra_runs,
        0)) AS Runs,
    SUM(IF(kind_out IN (1 , 2, 4, 6, 7, 8),
        1,
        0)) AS Wickets
FROM
    ball_by_ball BBB
        LEFT JOIN
    `database`.batsman_scored BS USING (match_id , over_id , ball_id , innings_no)
        LEFT JOIN
    `database`.extra_runs ER USING (match_id , over_id , ball_id , innings_no)
        LEFT JOIN
    `database`.wicket_taken WT USING (match_id , over_id , ball_id , innings_no)
WHERE
    bowler = 70
GROUP BY match_id
ORDER BY Wickets DESC , Runs;
```

**This is Output:**

```
+-------+------+---------+
| Balls | Runs | Wickets |
+-------+------+---------+
|    24 |   28 |       3 |
|    24 |   23 |       2 |
|    24 |   32 |       2 |
|    24 |   23 |       1 |
|    18 |   27 |       1 |
|    12 |   10 |       0 |
|    12 |   17 |       0 |
|     6 |   18 |       0 |
|    18 |   19 |       0 |
|    18 |   28 |       0 |
+-------+------+---------+
```

**This is my Final Query:**

```
SELECT 
    SUM(Balls) AS Balls,
    SUM(Runs) AS Runs,
    SUM(Wickets) AS Wickets
FROM
    (SELECT 
        COUNT(runs_scored) - SUM(IF(extra_type_id = 4, 1, 0)) AS Balls,
            SUM(runs_scored) + SUM(IF(extra_type_id IN (2 , 4), extra_runs, 0)) AS Runs,
            SUM(IF(kind_out IN (1 , 2, 4, 6, 7, 8), 1, 0)) AS Wickets
    FROM
        ball_by_ball BBB
    LEFT JOIN `database`.batsman_scored BS USING (match_id , over_id , ball_id , innings_no)
    LEFT JOIN `database`.extra_runs ER USING (match_id , over_id , ball_id , innings_no)
    LEFT JOIN `database`.wicket_taken WT USING (match_id , over_id , ball_id , innings_no)
    WHERE
        bowler = 70
    GROUP BY match_id
    ORDER BY Wickets DESC , Runs) AS A;
```

**This is Output:**

```
+-------+------+---------+
| Balls | Runs | Wickets |
+-------+------+---------+
|   180 |  225 |       9 |
+-------+------+---------+
```

**But I want to get the Maximum `Wickets` and `Runs` like below:**

```
+-------+------+---------+---------+
| Balls | Runs | Wickets | Max(W/R)|
+-------+------+---------+---------+
|   180 |  225 |       9 |    3/28 |
+-------+------+---------+---------+
```

> **Here `3` are `Wickets` and `28` are `Runs` which I got from `Subquery` first `Row`. Now how can i do that from my Final Query? I need to get `Subquery` first `Row` values which already sorted according to my requirement. I tried `WINDOWS FUNCTION` that not working.**

Comment: Do you have a fiddle or your window functions attempt?

Comment: `CONCAT(MAX(Wickets), '/', FIRST_VALUE(Runs) OVER (ORDER BY Wickets DESC))`

Comment: @danblack i tried what Akina suggested but that not work. to get `FIRST_VALUE(Runs)` i have to group by Runs which is not my solution.

Comment: @Akina i also tried that way but it's not working.  To get FIRST_VALUE(Runs) i have to group by Runs which is not my solution. That is the error without group `In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #4 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'A.Runs'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

Comment: Who doesn't like debugging partial fragments of SQL and error messages to a query they can't see.

Comment: *this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by* Remove `only_full_group_by` from session sql_mode before this query.

Comment: Alternatively - calculate `FIRST_VALUE(Runs) OVER (ORDER BY Wickets DESC)` in subquery, not in outer query.

Comment: @Akina i solved this by using ANY_VALUE() from MySQL Windows Function Reference, The Query like `CONCAT(MAX(Wickets), '/', First_Value(ANY_VALUE(Runs)) OVER ())` but is it efficient? because if i used `LAST_VALUE(ANY_VALUE(Runs))` i get same as `First_Value()`. Maybe it just return first value? or Random Value? **Also Same Things Happens when i remove `only_full_group_by`**